Scale and Move in one direction
I'm trying to adjust the selected portion inwards towards the center of the curve, and I'm not sure what to a) search to accomplish this or b) how to accomplish this. It's sorta like a scale and a move at the same time, but searching "blender sorta like a scale and move" doesn't exactly produce helpful results. Bonus points if I can have it snap to the next interval, since that's how far I want it to go.


If I understand correctly your request, you could first select the 3D Cursor option of the Transform Pivot Point panel:

Then put the 3D cursor at the center of the scale you want to achieve, and scale except on Z (SShiftZ):


That's it exactly. I always forget about the 3D cursor and what you can do with it.
